# Block traffic in azure front door based on claims

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-waf

I have a scenario in which I want to block some requests.
There is a property set in Identity claims and I want to deny the request based on that property.
Let's say that claims have a proper named "prop1".
I want to make sure that if prop1 has a value "value1" then I want to block that specific request.
Kindly share how can I do this.

Thanks

I have gone through the "Custom Rules" in "Front Door WAF policy" but I have found no option to check value in claims.

Answer (score 0):

To block some requests in Azure Front Door, check the below:

In your WAF policy go to Custom Rules add rule type and add condition match type as `string`  and match variable as `RequestUri`  is contain prop1 and value 1 action to be `deny`

[image]

The request which contains `cdnnfn` blocked successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Tutorial: Create WAF policy for Azure Front Door - Azure portal | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-create-portal)

Comment: This is not the solution actually.
You are using RequestUri, but I am talking about to block the request on the basis of claims value.

Comment: Azure Front Door does not support checking values in claims as part of its WAF policy. However, you can use Azure API Management in conjunction with Azure Front Door

Comment: Is there any other way?
I mean we can use any other service beside Azure API Management?

Comment: Using Azure Function proxies you can requests to your backend service and Configure Azure AD authentication ensure that the claims are available in the request context Add a policy to your Azure Function that checks the "prop1" claim in the request context. If the value of the claim is "value1 Configure Azure Front Door to route requests to your Azure Function.using routing rule based on the path, hostnam and Configure Azure Front Door to use the Azure Function as the backend for your Front Door instance.

Comment: Another option is to use Azure Application Gateway with Azure Front Door. You can configure Azure Application Gateway to perform authentication and authorization checks, and then use Azure Front Door to route requests to the Application Gateway